# Setting an array to one value

Tags: c

Is there an easier way in `C` to set an array to one value than using a `for` loop and going setting each value one by one?

Comment: [`memset`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/memset.html)?

Comment: Sometimes `wmemset` can also be useful.. :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're setting the array to all 0's, or if the array is an array of bytes, you can use [`memset`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset)

```
// Set myArray to all 0's
memset(myArray, 0, numberOfElementsInMyArray * sizeof(myArray[0]));
```

If you need to set it to something other than 0 in units larger than a byte (e.g. set an array of `int`s to 1's), then there is no standard function to do that -- you'll have to write your own for loop for that.

Comment: Why not substitute numberOfElementsInMyArray with `sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0])`  ;-)

Comment: @Ben Jackson: Because that doesn't work if `myArray` is a pointer to a dynamic array.

Comment: @Daniel: If you have an array of 4-byte ints that you want to initialize to 1, you need to fill it with the byte pattern `01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00` etc.  `memset(array, 1, size)` will give you `01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01` etc.

Comment: @Daniel - 1 doesn't fit into a byte if it is an int.

Comment: @Adam: I guess I shouldn't take "array" so literally in a beginner's question.  Good answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can set it to the same value,  but only to `0`

[How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

initialize all elements to `0`:

```
int myArray[10] = { 0 }; // all elements 0
```

There is an answer in that page for gcc as well.

Answer (score 5):

If it's an array of byte values, or you want to set each byte to a specific value, you can use `memset`:

```
char xyzzy[100];
int plugh[40];
memset (xyzzy, 7, sizeof (xyzzy)); // all chars set to 7.
memset (plugh, 0x42, sizeof (plugh));  // all integers set to (e.g.) 0x42424242.
```

Another possibility is to create a template of the correct size at initialisation time (either real initialisation as per below, or in an `init` function), then call `memcpy` to *blat <sup>(a)</sup>* it onto the real array at a later date.

```
static int template[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
int zorkmid[3];
memcpy (zorkmid, template, sizeof (zorkmid)); // ensure template is at
                                              // least as big as zorkmid.
```

This latter method is also handy for populating structures with a fixed pre-calculated value: initialise a dummy copy with the required fields set then `memcpy` it instead of manually setting all the fields each time you want a new instance.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> *Aside:* etymology of `blat`:

The [Jargon file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/index.html) (see the glossary for all the definitions) lists [`blat`](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/blat.html) as either the four metasyntactic variable `{foo, bar, thud, blat}`, or a synonym for `blast`, sense 1.

In turn, [`blast`](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/blast.html) (sense 1) is defined as a synonym of [`BLT`](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/BLT.html) (that's *not* the sandwich), which "referred to any large bit-field copy or move operation".

Comment: blat?  Can you provide a citation for that term?

Comment: Officially, no. It's in the BSD source code for memcpy IIRC, generally used for a larger than normal transfer of data. That, and grok, are my two favorite words :-)

Comment: grok is a most excellent word indeed.  I found a definition for blast in The Jargon File, which itself is listed as uncommon, which lists blat as a variation. http://catb.org/jargon/oldversions/jarg231.txt

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the value.  If it's zero, use `memset(a, 0, sizeof(a))`.  Otherwise, if it's a char array you can use memset with some other value.  But memset always works at the char level so if your array is not char only zero is likely to be meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old questions, but here are my two cents.

I guess that the computer has to iterate over each and every value one way or the other. So why not use a for-loop within a macro? This way your code does not clutter and you get something like a function.

For stack-allocated arrays (with compile-time defined size):

```
#define fill_array(array, value) \
    for(int i; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++) \
    {array[i]=value;}
```

For heap-alllocated arrays (iter is a pointer to the first entry of the array):

```
#define fill_array(iter, length, value) \
    for(int i; i < length; i++) \
    {*iter=value; iter++;}
```

Comment: `*iter=value; iter++;`  ===> `*iter++=value;`