# int array[30] = {0}; How this works in c?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

How this works(sets all values to 0)?

```
int array[28]= {0};
```

and why this not works(does not set all values to 4 but only the first value sets to 4 and others to 0)?

```
int array[28]= {4};
```

Comment: Here is the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066522/setting-an-array-to-one-value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The elements which are not initialized are set 0. In your first case you are initilizing it by providing it the value as 0 and rest are by default initialized as 0. In your second case the first values is intialized with 4 and rest as 0. The standard says:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

Answer (score 10):

In C, any element not listed in an initializer is implicitly being initialized to it's zero value.

`int array[28]= {0};` creates an array of 28 ints, and initializes the first element to 0. The remaining elements are not mentioned in the initializer get their zero value, which is 0 for ints.

`int array[28]= {4};` Works similarly. The first element is initialized to 4, and the remaining elements that are not mentioned in the initializer get their zero value.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because the standard demands it.

ISO/IEC:9899 (c99 standard) TC3 states:

> 6.7.8 Initialization

[...]

> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

What refers to the same paragraph at point 10:
(emphasis mine)

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. **If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then**:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.

So it is simply given that this has to happen, and thats why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[5] = {0}
```

All the elements will be initialized  to 0

```
int array[5] = {1,2,3}
```

In this case first element will be initialized to 1, second to 2, third to 3 and  rest of the elements to 0.

Comment: `int array[5] = {}`, is not allowed in C. In C++ its fine.

Comment: C forbids empty initializer braces, do you mean `{0}`?

Comment: A good example but it is not an answer to the question WHY does this happen.